# detecting the presence and version of IIS using MSBuild

Tags: iis, msbuild

What is the best way to determine whether IIS is installed and the version if it is using MSBuild?

So far I can think of using either WMI or Registry but is there an existing task in the MS Community Task, MS Web Deployment or MSBuild Extension tasks which already does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: MSBuild.Community.Tasks.IIS library, there will be WebBase.IISVersion, it can determine which version of IIS is installed.
Here's the link: http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

You can also use Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks library and tere is a function called Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.Configuration.InstalledProducts
Here's the link: http://sdctasks.codeplex.com/

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: any sample code of Microsoft.Sdc.Tasks.Configuration.InstalledProducts ?